# TopQuadrant Shacl Rule Engine Iterative inference

Tags: shacl, topbraid-composer

does the Shacl API Rule engine support sh:order for Rule execution as TopBraid Composer does.

I tested rule ordering in TBC and it goes iteratively until it reach a fixed point. No more rule to execute. I suspect that it is considered one-pass, but rule are prioritized and their result made available for the next rule to be execute in that same pass.

Anyhow, independently of how this is implemented, i wonder if it is a feature of the shacl rule engine or an implementation specific to TopBraid composer.

The following thread hint at the answer i am looking for but fall short.

[How to input inferred triples to (other) SHACL rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025359/how-to-input-inferred-triples-to-other-shacl-rules/64037679#64037679)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current SHACL API does not do the iterations out of the box. RuleEngine does a single iteration of all rules, and those rules may access each other's results following the outline at

https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/#rules-execution

To do iterative looping, simply call RuleEngine.executeAll until one round has not created any new inferences. Care needs to be taken to avoid infinite loops, as some rules may in theory produce blank nodes, random values etc. TopBraid Composer does this looping automatically.